# Cost price for block priced products

Tags: cpq

Let's say we're selling product licences, and have defined block pricing, e.g:

- 1-10: $100
- 10-50: $400
- 50-100: $700

But what about product cost? There is not the same cost for each range. So the margin gets wrong.

Can we block-price cost?

Answer (score 0):

What I read in [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_block_pricing.htm&type=5) here: Block pricing is useful when you sell products by packs or groups of various quantities and want to represent the pack as a single quote line. For example, a pack of one to 10 units costs $10, while a pack of 11–20 units costs $18. Sales reps can also use decreasing per-unit costs toward the end of each range as a selling incentive.

When a sales rep searches for a block-priced product, Salesforce CPQ shows its standard price on the Add Products page. However, when they add it to a quote, Salesforce CPQ evaluates its quantity and uses the appropriate block price for the quote line’s list unit price. They can then apply discounts as needed.

Also, I found another Salesforce link that talks as: [Apply a per unit price within Block Price Tiers in Salesforce CPQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000270668&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: Thanks, I've seen those, and both refer to price, not the cost. We need to compare cost and sales price, to find our margin.